# Deploy react app on heroku with webpack troubles

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, webpack

I get some troubles to deploy my react app on heroku.

I made a config production file for webpack 2.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

const extractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'main.[hash].css'
});

const HtmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    favicon: 'src/data/resources/img/logo/favicon.ico'
});

const ENVS = {
    'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    },
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'false'))
};
const PATHS = {
    app : path.join( __dirname, 'src'),
    build : path.join( __dirname, 'dist')
};

const config = {
    entry: [
        PATHS.app + "/index.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: 'bundle.[hash].js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [nodeModulesPath],
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [ {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                        removeComments: true,
                    }
                }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|gf|png|ico|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'img/',
                            publicPath: '/'
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractTextPlugin,
        HtmlPlugin,
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            minimize: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
            },
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(ENVS),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

When I run `npm run build`in my computer, I had no errors and I have my folder dist.

But on heroku after a push, I had this logs :

> build /tmp/build_646d8d781ce9c274343ec9ce9e11f2b4
>
> > webpack -p --config webpack-production.config.js clean-webpack-plugin: /tmp/build_646d8d781ce9c274343ec9ce9e11f2b4/dist
> >     has been removed. Hash: 2a8fc0ac2f35a1a04faf Version: webpack 2.5.1
> >     Time: 26063ms  [163] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 268 kB {0} [built] 
> >     [190] ./src/index.js 752 bytes {0} [built]  [191]
> >     ./~/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js 833 bytes {0} [built]  [192]
> >     ./~/babel-polyfill/~/core-js/fn/regexp/escape.js 107 bytes {0} [built]
> >     [372] ./~/babel-polyfill/~/core-js/shim.js 7.38 kB {0} [built]  [373]
> >     ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 69.7 kB {0} [built]  [374]
> >     ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css 41 bytes {0} [built]  [375]
> >     ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 41 bytes {0} [built]  [376]
> >     ./~/fixed-data-table/dist/fixed-data-table.css 41 bytes {0} [built] 
> >     [392] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]  [469]
> >     ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]  [470]
> >     ./~/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js 24.4 kB {0} [built]  [471] multi
> >     ./src/index.js 28 bytes {0} [built]  [472]
> >     ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
> >     23.1 kB [built]  [481] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 8.51 kB [built]
> >         + 468 hidden modules ERROR in ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/App' in
> >     '/tmp/build_646d8d781ce9c274343ec9ce9e11f2b4/src'  @ ./src/index.js
> >     11:11-31  @ multi ./src/index.js Child html-webpack-plugin for
> >     "index.html":
> >            [0] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 658 bytes {0} [built] Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
> >            [0] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.26 kB {0} [built]
> >            [1] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/fixed-data-table/dist/fixed-data-table.css
> >     6.27 kB {0} [built] Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
> >            [0] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.26 kB {0} [built]
> >            [1] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
> >     23.1 kB {0} [built] Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
> >            [0] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot 57 bytes {0} [built]
> >            [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.26 kB {0} [built]
> >            [2] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg 57 bytes {0} [built]
> >            [3] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 57 bytes {0} [built]
> >            [4] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 58 bytes {0} [built]
> >            [5] ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 59 bytes {0} [built]
> >            [6] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
> >     121 kB {0} [built] npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic npm ERR! argv
> >     "/tmp/build_646d8d781ce9c274343ec9ce9e11f2b4/.heroku/node/bin/node"
> >     "/tmp/build_646d8d781ce9c274343ec9ce9e11f2b4/.heroku/node/bin/npm"
> >     "run" "build" npm ERR! node v6.10.3 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR!
> >     code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! Olamee@0.1.0 build: `webpack -p --config
> >     webpack-production.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 2

This is the scripts for package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack-dev-server.config.js --hot --progress --colors --history-api-fallback",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack-production.config.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

It said me, I had a problem in the index.js to load the app component ! 
But I said, it's okay in my computer and of course in development mode.

My folder structure is like :

src

-app (all the components, reducers, actions etc)
  -data (all the style sheet, images, json file etc)
  -index.html
  -index.js

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace` on your local machine.